# Changing the predicate used in "Set" operation?

Tags: python, set

*Set* means to remove *duplicate* Items. Duplicate is identified by `a equals to b`.

Can I change `equals to` to a different predicate? I am trying to do this in Python but any language is fine.

I would like to know if there are any inbuilt set mechanisms to reduce `['aaaa', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c']` to `['aaaa', 'bb' 'c']`. Here duplicate is defined by if it is `substring of something else`. I feel there is a similarity in how `duplicates` are found. But if it's using hashing then I could be wrong.

Comment: I think your confusion that *set* means to remove duplicates is incorrect. Sets are a data type that don't allow duplicates; IE every item is unique and is tested by hashing its items, meaning all items must be hashable types (have a `__hash__` method) -- You can get the effect you're looking for another way, but trying to use `set` may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I mean "Sets" in mathematical sense. But I got your point. I guess Sets are computed in O(n) Time in that case?

Comment: So, what's the predicate you want to substitute? You can use comprehensions for this. For example `new_list = [item for item in old_list if item is not None]` would eliminate all items that are `None`

Comment: Nah those are not my use cases. Check the edit.

Comment: Yeah, so sets do indeed use hashing. You could use the `filter` builtin for something like this. Filter takes a function and an iterable and returns a new iterable with only the items for which `func(item)` evaluates True. Which is equivalent to `[item for item in the_list if function(item)]` as far as I know, that's the closest to what you're asking for. Comprehensions use generators which are memory efficient iterators. Same with `filter` in Python3 and `itertools.ifilter` in Python2

Comment: Yeah your point is taken. But the normal filter would be O(n2) to solve this problem. So I was thinking I can combine with an better inbuilt mechanism for data traversal.

Comment: The operational cost would depend on the filter or comprehension used. But I don't think that's a good metric for the performance of the filter. Keep in mind that `filter` is implemented in C and would perform much faster than its list comprehension counterpart which would do the same number of operations in Python, as opposed to C.

Comment: "Substring of" is not an equivalence relation (as it's not a symmetric), so it's not a good candidate for equality.